# declare, initialize, and setOnClickListener for a variable in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been looking around stack for 3 days now, and still haven't been able to solve this problem. I might not be looking in the proper areas, so please let me know if this question already has a semi-direct answer to it somewhere.

Basically, I have a tabbed activity where I created fragments for each tab, and I realize now, after searching through questions and answers for 3 days, that there's like a different syntax to link a button to the java file.
I'm trying to get this button to simply dissappear after it's click but I keep getting the error saying that it's accessed from within an inner class and needs to be final?

Please help me out with this, fairly new to coding (rep is exactly 1) trying not to bring that down right now.
Any help is appreciated!

[image: imports (there's a lot of unused ones..)]

[image: code for button and onCreate class and everything I've really done so far..(which isn't much)]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What happens when you set the button to final?

Comment: @Mars Thanks, when I add final to the button, it doesn't give me any errors in the ide itself, but when I run it on the emulator or usb debugging with my phone, it crashes.

Comment: Another error, another question. Check the android monitor for an error message!

Comment: @Mars don't understand anything in logcat.....

Comment: Worth studying, since that's like 99% of programming :p    try learning "how to debug with stack trace"

Comment: Is there a reason why my answer got unaccepted?

Comment: I've updated the answer, should probably answer your next question about errors as well

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring your button like this:

```
final Button buttonOS = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOS);
```

Also, you should move your logic from `onCreateView()` to `onStart()`. Your button hasn't been created yet, so you'll likely get null errors with `getView()`

By the way, if you click to bring your cursor to the error, you can press Alt+Enter to bring up the autocorrect menu.

Comment: @cricket_007 Would getView().findViewById cause an error? I think getView should work fine, it's the later setVisibility that would error out, after findViewById returns null

Comment: It'll return a null view if it's used before its returned by onCreateView

Comment: @cricket_007 But findViewById will also null out until after createView, no?

Comment: Nevermind, it doesn't. Learn something new every day

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v.setVisibility(View.GONE)`.

You don't necessarily need the button reference

Comment: So do you think that the errors in my Choreographer.java, Handler.java, and looper.java have any cause for the app to keep crashing whenever I debug? Also, what does the "v" stand for cause honestly I'm a ninth grader just doing this as a pass-time

Comment: What other errors? The Handler, Looper, Choreographer, are not error messages. Just extra information in the Logcat. Your actual classes will be highlighted in Blue for you to click on... Anyways,  `onClick(View v)`... That is the View/Button that is being clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in onViewCreated instead of onCreateView:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOS).setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help setting the button visibility in the click method

Comment: Just put it inside the listener like you did

Comment: What do you mean? It still needs to be final, or looked up with findViewById

Answer (score 0):

> Try this ...first declare the variables Globally

```
View view;
Button button;
```

> In your onCreateView

```
button = (Button ) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //do something here (click function)
    }
});
```

Comment: Crashes my app.. logcat shows errors in choreographer Handler and looper.. I've never even been to any of those files.

Comment: @Chrome The stack trace is a sequence of calls leading up to the error. Keep following the trace until you find code that you recognize! In this case, most likely "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.View.setVisibility(View.Visibility)' on a null object reference at ~~~~~~~.onCreateView(~~~.java:54)